# how to make LVMs at available boot? kernel panic - dracut cannot find logical volumes after kernel upgrade in CentOS 6.6

Tags: centos, kernel, boot, lvm

I have a centoOS 6.6 vmware vm that I ran `yum update` on which upgraded the kernel

after reboot, I started getting this:

```
dracut Warning: No root device "block:/dev/vg_myhost/lv_root" found

dracut Warning: LVM /dev/vg_myhost/lv_root not found
dracut Warning: LVM /dev/vg_myhost/lv_swap not found


Kernel panic - not syncing:  Attempted to kill init!
Pid: 1, comm: init Not tainted 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 #1
panic
do_exit
fput
do_group_exit
sys_exit_group
system_call_fastpath
```

I added rdshell to my kernel params and rebooted again.  After the same error, the boot sequence dropped into rdshell.

at the shell, I ran `lvm lvdisplay`, and it found the volumes, but they were marked as **LV Status  NOT available**

```
dracut:/#lvm lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_myhost/lv_root
  LV Name                lv_root
  VG Name                vg_myhost
...
  LV Status              NOT available
...
```

I then was able to make these active.

```
dracut:/# lvm vgchange -ay
 2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg_myhost" now active

dracut:/# exit

...boots normally...
```

After making these available and exiting dracut shell, the OS booted just fine.

but after rebooting again I hit the same problem.

**note** this all works fine if I boot with the old kernel

new kernel args

```
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/vg_myhost/lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_myhost/lv_root rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=128M rd_LVM_LV=vg_myhost/lv_swap  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM  rdshell
```

old kernel args:

```
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/vg_myhost/lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_myhost/lv_root rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=128M rd_LVM_LV=vg_myhost/lv_swap  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
```

my question:  how do I make these volumes seen by the new kernel at boot time?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue on my RHEL 7 machine. But it use GRUB2.

When I remove those `rd_LVM_LV=` in kernel args. Press <kbd>e</kbd> before booting, remove those `rd_LVM_LV=` in kernel args, type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> I can then boot successfully.

Steps to permanently solve on RHEL 7:

1. Open `/etc/default/grub` remove those `rd_LVM_LV=` in "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX"
2. Run `grub2-mkconifg` to create a new `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`